# What is this batch in the verbose output during model training in tensorflow 2.3.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have specified the **batch size = 16** and **steps per epoch = 1000**. The **total samples in the dataset are 2628**. The verbose output is shown below as well as in the image link.

```
Epoch 26/100
1000/1000 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - batch: 499.5000 - size: 16.0000 - loss: 0.2308 - Z_loss: 0.0200 - Z_logits_loss: 0.2108 
lr = 0.001961161382496357, step = 26000
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3168s 3s/step - batch: 499.5000 - size: 16.0000 - loss: 0.2308 - Z_loss: 0.0200 - Z_logits_loss: 0.2108
```

What does `batch = 499.5000` mean?

[Model training Verbose output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMwqm.png)

Comment: Are you using a custom network? I don't think these are default outputs from TF2, but rather specific losses that belong to a network that you are training on.

Comment: Yes, It is a custom network! The model can be viewed at below notebook link:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ueRmHXgcAQ6kswvULjzlD0-E3kCk4tEA?usp=sharing